# React / Node / Express page giving 404 on some iphones

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

OK, this is a weird one. I have a react/nodejs app deployed on heroku. One route gives intermittent and bizarre behaviours. This doesn't happen on locally running servers, and it only happens on some phone browsers as far as I can tell (my android and iphone fail but i know of iphones that are working as well as androids that are)

The url in question on my staging environment is

https://pure-escarpment-97621.herokuapp.com/auth

So in general, this will return an "Authorising" spinner page, but in some cases on phones, I get an instant 404 returned. I'll try and drop some relevant code here

My react client proxies to my node/express app using the following in the package.json

```
 "proxy": "http://localhost:5001"
```

My App.js has the following route

```
 <Route path="/auth" render={(props) => {
      console.log("hit auth in client");
      this.handleAuthentication(props);
      return <Callback auth={auth} {...props} />
    }}/>
```

handleAuthentication does the following (so calling the server /auth route)

```
var hdrs = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${parsedQueryString.access_token}`
  };

  console.log("about to fetch auth server side from client")

  fetch('/auth', {
    headers : hdrs,
    method: 'post',
  })
  .then(results => {

   // this.setSession(parsedQueryString);
      return results.json();
      window.location.href = '/';
  })
  .then(data => {
  //  console.log("Results = " + JSON.stringify(data));
      this.setSession(data);
      window.location.href = '/';
    })
```

I dont think the backend stuff is needed here, as it never seems to get that far. In fact, i think it's just some kind of strange heroku setup issue that I dont understand.

Anyone got any ideas? This is really frustrating.

Cheers

Mark

---

EDIT:

Looking at the access logs, it appears to be an issue with service-worker.js

With Mobile

```
2018-06-18T19:11:05.259855+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth" host=fierce-savannah-70710.herokuapp.com request_id=5ee04ac9-eaf4-4121-8b1c-6721d891c0b2 fwd="212.159.122.237" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=24ms status=404 bytes=380 protocol=http
```

From Web

```
2018-06-18T19:12:17.319382+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/service-worker.js" host=fierce-savannah-70710.herokuapp.com request_id=786c9dc2-0940-4e94-88c7-44ef3542619d fwd="212.159.122.237" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
```

EDIT:

app.js

```
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var session = require('express-session');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var bearerToken = require('express-bearer-token');
    var index = require('./routes/index');
    var posts = require('./routes/posts');
    var users = require('./routes/users');
    var auth = require('./routes/auth');
    var accounts = require('./routes/accounts')
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var config = require('./config')



    var app = express();

    app.use(session({
      secret: config.session.secret,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      resave: false
    }));

    app.use(bearerToken());

    // view engine setup
    // app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    // app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    // Priority serve any static files.
    app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './client/build')));

    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(logger('dev'));

    var dburl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/curie'

    if (config.db_user)
    {
      dburl = 'mongodb://' + config.db_user + ':' + config.db_pwd + '@'  + config.db_url + '/' + config.db_name
    }

    console.log("connecting to db " + dburl); 
    mongoose.set('debug', true);
    mongoose.connect(dburl, {
      useMongoClient: true,
      /* other options */
    });


    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    //app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')));


    app.use('/', index);
    app.use('/posts', posts);
    app.use('/users', users);
    app.use('/auth', auth);
    app.use('/accounts', accounts);


    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    });

    // error handler
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      // set locals, only providing error in development
      res.locals.message = err.message;
      res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

      // render the error page
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error');
    });

    // All remaining requests return the React app, so it can handle routing.
    app.get('*', function(request, response) {
      response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './client/build', 'index.html'));
    });

    module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Please comment more about your server, or even the logs there. For the response to be 404 it means the server is done with the request - and returned in error. Sometimes a 404 or 400 could be your server's default like if an exception is thrown in your code on that one weird corner case. Whatever the reason, a "404 response" is the server being finished with your request, so your server code/logs are important. (If you could not even talk to your server, pure client side, you'd get a 504 or something like that where no connection could even be made.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So I have done a bit more investigation - the only thing that i found that could possibly cause this was service-worker so i created a deployment without that and now i get the same 404 when using the app on desktop web browser. This only happens on an instance deployed on Heroku. It seems that i just cannot get the /auth endpoint to return the appropriate page. I'll try and add some more detail to the above for clarification

Comment: It's like that 404 is the _correct_ response. Your desktop was not showing 404 because the service worker had cached a valid response in the past that no longer exists. Your server should be directly (almost all) traffic to your React's index.html file. Your React routes do not exist on the server, so it will hit a 404 if it attempts to look for them. Your /auth route exists only in your React index.html file, for example, not on the server.

Comment: Yeah, i think the problem is that my server isn't redirecting /auth to my react index.html for some reason. I have the react routing set up and / gets redirected there and handled fine, but /auth doesnt. I'll add the app.js code to the original